# Set up a an IF formula through VBA but if cell is blank return an empty cell

Tags: vba, excel

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

I am currently trying to set an IF formula through VBA that refers to the cell above. If the cell is equal to 0 then it would return a blank value other wise it would return the same value as above.

I am using Belgium setting hence if formula has a comma and not a semicolon
Below is the code. note that the first line help me refer to the cell above.

```
v = i - 1
Cells(i, "F").Formula = "=if(F" & i - 1"=0,"""",F" & i - 1")"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're missing a couple `&` operators: `"=if(F" & i - 1 & "=0,"""",F" & i - 1 & ")"`

Comment: Thank you so much Cominterm. I should have catch that - I guess it s a sign that it is time to go to bed :). Thanks again!